# How to use \copy in psql after connecting to a database via URI in a batch file?

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, uri, psql

I want to make a .bat file that will go to a directory, change code page (beacuse my folders contain characters from my native language) then open database in psql and then using \copy export some tables from DB to folder on my computer, then quit database and close the command. If I do it manually it works like a charm, but .bat file stops after entering database.

```
    cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin
    chcp 1250
    psql "postgres://<heres_my_URI>"
    \copy <table_name> to 'G:\<path>\name.csv' with 
 DELIMITER ',' header csv; 
    \copy <table_name> to 'G:\<path>\name.csv' with 
 DELIMITER ',' header csv;  
    \q
    exit
```

I want the .bat file to download csv's to the path and close itself after.

But .bat is doing fine until it enters database, then it just shows:

```
<mydatabase_name> =>
```

and until I press `\q` or

```
\copy <table_name> to 'G:\<path>\name.csv' with 
     DELIMITER ',' header csv;
```

manually, nothing will happen. After I quit DB, it shows me all the errors about \copy not being recognizable. How do I make it work? Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put all statements to execute by psql in a separate file, not in 
the main `.bat` file:

`.bat` file:

```
chcp 1250
psql "postgres://<heres_my_URI>" -f script.sql
exit
```

`script.sql`:

```
\copy <table_name> to 'G:\<path>\name.csv' with  DELIMITER ',' header csv
\copy <table_name> to 'G:\<path>\name.csv' with  DELIMITER ',' header csv
```

Make sure that each `\copy` command fits in a single line, because it must. It doesn't have to be ended with a semi-colon though.

Comment: It still ignores the script.sql as another spare argument and proceeds to the database... I can't understand what is wrong... script.sql should be in the same folder as the .bat file? (It is, but I'm asking nevertheless)

Comment: @ThorOdinson: if you think that the -f argument is being eaten by the URI then please try to reverse them: `psql -f script.sql ...other arguments`

Comment: YES! It finally worked! Thank you so much! (I just added the path to the script.sql file and switched the order of arguments)

Comment: @ThorOdinson: Good! Welcome to SO and please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if we're done with this question.

Answer (score -1):

You could pass the sql with the command parameter:
psql "postgres://" -c "copy  to 'G:\\name.csv' with DELIMITER ',' header csv; copy  to 'G:\\name.csv' with 
 DELIMITER ',' header csv;"

Comment: Still cmd tells me it was just an excessive argument (everything that follows "postgres://") and it was ignored. Proceeds to database and shows me:
    <mydatabase_name> =>
again.